# C# Winforms TextBox Validation check

Tags: c#, winforms

I have 3 pairs of textboxes in a windows form :-

```
TxtboxSourceFolder1 -> TxtboxDestinationFolder1
TxtboxSourceFolder2 -> TxtboxDestinationFolder2
TxtboxSourceFolder3 -> TxtboxDestinationFolder3
```

I am creating a `List<string> SrcFolders` and a `List<string> DestFolders`.

Now I have to validate the user input:-

1) Is there a value for TxtboxSourceFolder1, If yes, Is there a corresponding value in TxtboxDestinationFolder1 ? If all answers are yes, and the values are legitimate then add them to corresponding lists. And then repeat.

To me it seems like to check if a textbox is empty:-

```
    private int ConstructSourceDestinationFolderList()
    {
        if (Directory.Exists(txtboxSrcFolder1.Text) && Directory.Exists(txtboxDestFolder1.Text))
        {
            trans.szSourceFolderList.Add(txtboxSrcFolder1.Text.ToString());
            trans.szDestinationFolderList.Add(txtboxDestFolder1.Text);
        }
        else
        {
            return 1;
        }

        if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtboxSrcFolder2.Text))
        {
            if (Directory.Exists(txtboxSrcFolder2.Text) && Directory.Exists(txtboxDestFolder2.Text))
            {
                trans.szSourceFolderList.Add(txtboxSrcFolder2.Text);
                trans.szDestinationFolderList.Add(txtboxDestFolder2.Text);
            }
            else
            {
                return 1;
            }
        }


        if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtboxSrcFolder3.Text))
        {
            if (Directory.Exists(txtboxSrcFolder3.Text) && Directory.Exists(txtboxDestFolder3.Text))
            {
                trans.szSourceFolderList.Add(txtboxSrcFolder3.Text);
                trans.szDestinationFolderList.Add(txtboxDestFolder3.Text);
            }
            else
            {
                return 1;
            }
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

Now I have to do the same thing for all of the textboxes. This seems cumbersome. Is there a more compact way to design this validation?

Comment: Generalize it to a method that takes the text of the textboxes maybe? Doesn't sound too terribly cumbersome. Could always write it and post to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: The issue I have with the approach is, I am accessing each textbox by name and hence cant just iterate through a list and make it more generalized.

Comment: You don't need two tests. IsNullOrWhiteSpace catches also the Empty condition

Comment: That's not what I'm saying. You only have 3 pairs, so just make a method  like `bool ValidateTextBoxes(string, string)` which does all the work, then just call it 3 times like `if (ValidateTextBoxes(tb1.Text, tb2.Text)) { /* do stuff */ }`. Shouldn't be too much code, I wouldn't think... Also @Steve is correct. No need for that second check.

Comment: The number 3 looks very arbitrary.  Why not use 1 and an Add button.  The list needs to be visible as well so the user can correct mistakes.  Now it all gets simple to use and equally simple to write.

Comment: @DangerZone I edited my answer with the validation code. Doesn't look very pretty to me, maybe I am misunderstanding you.

Comment: @Philo - You are misunderstanding. See how much repeated code you have? The only difference is which textbox's text is being validated. Break the repeated code into another method so that you do not need to repeat it 3 times.

Comment: @DangerZone 3 source and 3 destination folders. The check only happens when user clicks a button. Once the button is clicked, the validation begins as:- 1) Atleast one source and one destination folder needs values. 2) The additional 2 Source and Destination folders may have values. 3) If they don't have legitimate pairs that is also an issue. 
The folders have unique names and they need to be validated individually, hence I cannot put them in a generic method.

Comment: Also, why not just return true/false instead of an integer since it appears that your return values are either 1 or 0?

Comment: @Dayan 1or 0, true or false.... binaries.

Comment: @Philo Yeah... But you are utilizing a whole byte to represent true/false. Why not just use a bit for true or false?

Comment: @Dayan because the code is so simplistic that it doesn't matter...